# Where I can find the old docs of GitLab API?

Tags: api, gitlab, gitlab-8, gitlab-api

On the main site of [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) I cannot find any documentation for old v3 API version. Where it can be found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [section **V3 to V4**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/v3_to_v4.html) of
the API documentation there is a link to the [old V3 API doc](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/8-16-stable/doc/api/README.md).

*Beware that the V3 API is going to be removed in **GitLab 9.5** to be released in  August 22, 2017.*

Comment: thank you for link. We're going to move to v4, but we still use v3, so this doc is helpful for me.